# Count grouped values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

customer

```
id      name
1       John
2       Kevin
```

customer_property

```
id      customer_id    code              value       
1       1              main_course                   
2       1              main_course                   
3       1              drink                         
4       1              drink                         
5       1              cash              100
```

I want to count courses and drinks that each customer have ordered.
I can count drinks by this query:

```
SELECT
  c.name,
  COUNT(DISTINCT cp.id) AS drinks_count
FROM customer AS c
  JOIN customer_property AS cp ON c.id=cp.customer_id
WHERE cp.code="drink"
  GROUP BY cp.id
```

That is working fine. My questoin - is it possible to count courses in the same query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use conditional sum for this, and doing group by `cp.id` will give you that many rows you have in that table, you may do it as `c.name`

```
SELECT
  c.name,
  sum(cp.code="drink") AS drinks_count,
  sum(cp.code="main_course") AS main_course_count,
FROM customer AS c
  JOIN customer_property AS cp ON c.id=cp.customer_id
  GROUP BY c.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT
c.name,
cp.code,
COUNT(DISTINCT cp.id) AS drink_or_course_count
FROM customer AS c
JOIN customer_property AS cp ON c.id=cp.customer_id
WHERE cp.code="drink" or cp.code="main_course"
GROUP BY cp.id,cp.code
```

Grouping by ID of the person **AND** code will split the count by code. Result will be something like

```
 Name  Code  drink_or_course_count
 John  drink  5
 john  main_course 3
```